# Maximization in Mathematica using matrix and vector notation

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve a simple maximization problem in *Mathematica*, using matrix and vector notation.

```
myVect = {{x}, {y}}
offDiag = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}
Maximize[{0.5*Transpose[myVect].offDiag.myVect, 
  Transpose[myVect].{{2}, {2}} - 1 == 0}, {myVect}]
```

So I'm just trying to maximize the area of a rectangle with the circumference of 1, using this notation (I'll need it for more complex problems later). However, I get this error message:

> Maximize::ivar: {{x},{y}} is not a valid variable. >>

Both the objective function and the equality constraint by themselves seem to work. What am I doing wrong? Is this a syntax error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three problems with your posted code.

1. Your objective function is a 1x1 matrix rather than a scalar.
2. Your constraint equation is malformed. One side is a 1x1 matrix, the other is a scalar. They should both be scalars.
3. The variables should be in a flat list.

@Willinski already gave [a more natural way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92235/9391%20%22a) of expressing vectors in Mathematica, so that the `.` acts like contraction (returning a scalar) rather than matrix multiplication (returning a 1x1 matrix). It works because Mathematica automatically interprets a `List` as a 1xn or nx1 matrix depending on the context.

In case you really need to keep your matrix notation for `myVect` (possibly for some kind of generalization), then you need to make sure the objective function and constraint equation are scalars. For the posted code, you can achieve this by using `Part`. The variables have to be a flat list, so I flattened it and then used an anonymous function to reconstruct the formatted version of the results.

```
myVect = {{x}, {y}}
offDiag = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}
Maximize[{
 (0.5*Transpose[myVect].offDiag.myVect)[[1, 1]],
 ({{x, y}}.{{2}, {2}})[[1, 1]] - 1 == 0
 }, Flatten@myVect] //
 {#[[1]], myVect -> (myVect /. #[[2]])} &
```

Answer (score 8):

Your corrected code:

```
myVect = {x, y};
offDiag = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
Maximize[1/2*myVect.offDiag.myVect, myVect.{2, 2} - 1 == 0, myVect]

{1/16, {x -> 1/4, y -> 1/4}}
```